# Mongoexport halts when it reaches 101 records

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I'm trying to dump a MongoDB collection from a **remote server** to a **local** JSON file.

First, I do some ssh port forwarding to begin with:

`ssh -NL 12345:localhost:27017 $REMOTE_USERNAME@$REMOTE_HOST &`

Then, the export itself:

`mongoexport -h $MONGODB_URL -d $MONGODB_DBNAME -c $MONGODB_COLLECTION -o $BACKUP_FILE --pretty`

What I would normally get is something like this:

```
2019-02-07T14:58:15.322-0400    writing bubeIO.requests to
2019-02-07T14:58:18.754-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  0/2773  (0.0%)
2019-02-07T14:58:21.754-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  10/2773  (0.3%)
2019-02-07T14:58:24.754-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  20/2773  (0.6%)
...
...
2019-02-07T14:59:00.754-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  2773/2773  (100.0%)
```

But, what I'm getting is this:

```
2019-02-07T14:58:15.322-0400    writing bubeIO.requests to
2019-02-07T14:58:18.754-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  0/2773  (0.0%)
2019-02-07T14:58:21.754-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  0/2773  (0.0%)
2019-02-07T14:58:24.754-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  0/2773  (0.0%)
2019-02-07T14:58:27.753-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  101/2773  (3.6%)
2019-02-07T14:58:30.753-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  101/2773  (3.6%)
2019-02-07T14:58:33.754-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  101/2773  (3.6%)
2019-02-07T14:58:36.753-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  101/2773  (3.6%)
2019-02-07T14:58:39.753-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  101/2773  (3.6%)
2019-02-07T14:58:42.753-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  101/2773  (3.6%)
2019-02-07T14:58:45.754-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  101/2773  (3.6%)
2019-02-07T14:58:48.753-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  101/2773  (3.6%)
2019-02-07T14:58:51.753-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  101/2773  (3.6%)
2019-02-07T14:58:54.754-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  101/2773  (3.6%)
2019-02-07T14:58:57.753-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  101/2773  (3.6%)
2019-02-07T14:59:00.594-0400    [........................]  bubeIO.requests  101/2773  (3.6%)
2019-02-07T14:59:00.594-0400    Failed: error writing data for collection `bubeIO.requests` to disk: error reading collection: read tcp [::1]:61276->[::1]:12345: use of closed network connection
```

As you can see, it goes from 0 to 101 real quick and then it doesn't go anywhere from there until timeout.

It worked nicely before for remote dumps and suddenly this starts to happen. **Local dumps work just fine**, so this could be a networking issue?

Can anyone give me a direction on how to solve this?

PS: mongod and mongoexport are both version 4.0.2

---

**EDIT**

**It started working again after I freed a total of 13 GB hd space.** Maybe the disk could not hold the whole uncompressed collection, so I'm getting deeper in mongoexport's inner workings and disk usage. Thanks to @priyanka-kariya and @Stennie.

Comment: Hi @PriyankaKariya, I did it and the disk had only 3 GB of free space. I cleaned it a little and now the dump is working ok, so thank you a lot! Interesting thing is the collection that I'm dumping is only 61 MB.

Comment: @VictorValente, Did you try to give the some "records" limits of collection during the mongoexport time. for example ( mongoexport --host localhost --db test --collection foo  | head -100 > a.json)

Comment: 101 documents (or up to 1MB of results) is the default size for the first batch of results in a query. Subsequent operations use larger batches (up to the 16MB message size limit). This looks like a networking error or timeout with your port forwarding, but there isn't enough information to be sure. The error happens after about 45 seconds, which seems very short for a timeout. What type of remote deployment are you connecting to (standalone, replica set, or sharded cluster)? If you are using a replica set, are you including `replicaSet` in the connection string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the disk space on target machine